# Uncertain about R blogdown workflow

Tags: r, rstudio, blogdown

When I use the RStudio add-in to create a new post (in my case an .Rmarkdown) file, I'm not certain of when to "knit" vs. "serve the site" to get the needed output.  And sometimes a see a Preview button and at other times I don't.   I'm trying a test now with the `yaml` header below, and I'm getting a file not found error when attempting to render preview html (the error message doesn't say which file wasn't found).  I also uncertain on whether you need to `output:` line in the header.

```
---
title: How Can Machine Learning be Reliable When the Sample is Adequate for Only One
  Feature?
author: Frank Harrell
date: '2018-01-11'
slug: ml-sample-size
output:
    blogdown::html_page
categories: []
tags:
  - prediction
  - machine-learning
  - sample-size
  - validation
  - precision
csl: american-medical-association.csl
bibliography: harrelfe.bib
---
```

Comment: use `blogdown::build_site()` instead of the "knir" button. And use `blogdown::serve_site()` instead of "preview" button

Answer (score 4):

[Section 1.7](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/workflow.html) of the **blogdown** book mentioned a recommended workflow. In particular, it says:

> Click the RStudio addin “Serve Site” to preview the site in RStudio Viewer. [...] Do not click the `Knit` button on the RStudio toolbar.

Comment: I also found that I like to run `hugo server` at the command line, previewing the web site in the regular browser.  This process is fast.

Comment: @FrankHarrell If you need it to be really fast, you may read the Appendix D.2: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/livereload.html In terms of speed, you cannot beat `options(blogdown.generator.server = TRUE, blogdown.hugo.server = c("-D", "-F", "--navigateToChanged"))` with `blogdown::serve_site()`.

Comment: This rocks.  I put the `options()` call in my `~/.Rprofile`.  The only trick I had to realize is to call `serve_site()` before I made any source file changes.  Now I get my browser automatically showing the latest changed page.  Wonderful.

Comment: Yeah, `--navigateToChanged` is magical. From my experience, it occasionally leads to a 404 page when you create a new post, but it is very hard to reliably reproduce the issue. When it occurs, just refresh your browser.